# Run time issue in ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, .net, controls, runtime, overlap

I am new to web development in ASP.NET and I have just designed a small website. Though in design time I have my controls placed correctly, at run time the controls appear overlapped. I have seen the source view and the values for left and top were fine. Have a look into these screen shots:

At design time:

[image]

At run time in Chrome and IE:

[image]

In Mozilla:

[image]

My code in source view for the text boxes:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
    style="z-index: 1; left: 102px; top: 339px; position: absolute"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
    style="z-index: 1; left: 247px; top: 327px; position: absolute"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" 
    style="z-index: 1; left: 248px; top: 360px; position: absolute"></asp:TextBox>
```

There might be a simple solution, but since I am new to this, please let me know what has to be done.

Comment: When using absolute position you must also specify width and height. I'm surprised you see anything at all..

Answer (score 0):

I would reorganize your markup a bit. You could try:

```
<div style="position: absolute; left: 102px; top: 327px;">
    <div id="left_column" style="float:left">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <div id="right_column" style="float: left; margin-left: 15px;">
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" />
    </div>
</div>
```

If you want more spacing between the elements add some margin og padding.

Comment: That makes my textboxes displayed in a row. More over writing the `div` tags manually might be tedious if I later have many of such controls on my page spread randomly(not in a single row or column).

Comment: I would argue that it is more tedious to user the designer to rearrange your controls every time you add a new one to the page. You best option is to use some styles (CSS) like the @fo1 suggested (Although I would stay away from absolute positioning.